# what is the convention for the location of my bash scripts?

Tags: bash, scripting, convention

I suspect the convention is to leave my bash scripts in one of the directories of the default $PATH.  Which?

I imagine 2 kinds of scripts so I am asking for 2 answers, please.

1. scripts for root user
2. scripts for regular users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` for users and `/usr/local/sbin` for root is generally the place where user-created scripts meant to be run locally are located

Comment: I would say that `~/bin` is the place for user-created scripts. `/usr/local/bin` would be for root-created scripts meant to be run *by* users.